# Use of connect after recvfrom with socket

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, serversocket

Hi i want to wait the first message of a client as a server with a UDP Protocol so i send a message when I create the client socket and I use a recvfrom to get the message and the adress of the client.It works pretty good I can read the message in my buffer but after this operation I try to connect the server to the client address but this operation return a value of -1 for the connect process and I don't understand the reason.Here is my function wait for client the error is at the end when I try to connect to clientaddr.

```
int wait_for_client(int sfd){

    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
    int len;
    char buf[32];
    len = sizeof(clientaddr);
    int rec_stat = recvfrom(sfd, buf, 32, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&clientaddr, (socklen_t *)&len);
    if(rec_stat<0){
        printf("echec de receive");
        fflush(stdout);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    fflush(stdout);
    int connect_status = connect(sfd,(struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr,sizeof(clientaddr));
    if(connect_status == -1){
        printf("failed to connect to client\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    return sfd;
}
```

Comment: *but this operation crash*. Do you actually mean the process crashed or just that the call failed? If it crashed please provide details of how it crashed.

Comment: @kaylum no I explained myself badly sorry the procees crash and returns -1 so the return value of connect is -1

Comment: Call `perror` to get a more detailed error string.

Comment: If the incoming UDP packet contains 32 or more bytes and none of the first 32 bytes in the packet are 0, then your printf() calls will try to print out an unterminated string and will read past the end of the ‘buf’ array.  You can avoid that possibility by manually writing a 0 byte to the last char in ‘buf’.

Comment: @kaylum it tells me invalid argument but I don't know why because I think that I use my args in a right way

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Yes I know but I send a special message so the size is ok but it is the connect operation that is an issue for me

Comment: thank you very much i found my problem

Comment: Good to hear. Please consider posting an answer for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: You should pass `len`, the actual length of the client address, instead of `sizeof(clientaddr)` to `connect()`.

Comment: @user207421 and `len` should be declared as `socklen_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner "*You can avoid that possibility by manually writing a 0 byte to the last char in ‘buf’.*" - or better, pass the return value of `recvfrom()` to `printf()` as a length specifier. Writing a 0 byte will corrupt data if 32 bytes were actually received. You would have to increase the buffer size to 33 to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because my clientaddr is declared as sockaddr_in but my client was created as sockaddr_in6. So the mistake was the struct of my clientaddr